# Why grep failed to use $_?

Tags: regex, perl

Below is a simple perl example, $_ should be ranging from 0 to 6, and for each iteration, the strings that contain corresponding number should be extracted out. However, the result is not what I expected. I was told that `$_` probably needs to be quoted so I used `\Q` and `\E`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for (0..6) {
    print ("$_: ".(join ", ", (grep /\Q$_\E/, ("12", "123", "00", "0012")))."\n");
}
```

What I expected to get:

```
0: 00, 0012
1: 12, 123, 0012
2: 12, 123, 0012
3: 123
4:
5:
6:
```

What I actually get:

```
0: 12, 123, 00, 0012
1: 12, 123, 00, 0012
2: 12, 123, 00, 0012
3: 12, 123, 00, 0012
4: 12, 123, 00, 0012
5: 12, 123, 00, 0012
6: 12, 123, 00, 0012
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're wanting `$_` to be the iterator from the `for` loop, but it's actually being set to the values to the right of the `grep`.

Your `grep` is comparing each number to itself like so:

```
grep {$_ =~ /\Q$_\E/} "12", "123", "00", "0012"
```

You need to give the `for` loop a named iterator instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $num ( 0 .. 6 ) {
    print "$num: ", join( ", ", grep /\Q$num\E/, "12", "123", "00", "0012" ), "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
0: 00, 0012
1: 12, 123, 0012
2: 12, 123, 0012
3: 123
4: 
5: 
6:
```

Answer (score 5):

`grep` trumps implicit `$_` foreach variable; workaround is to use explicit foreach variable,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $i (0..6) {
    print ("$i: ".(join ", ", (grep /\Q$i\E/, ("12", "123", "00", "0012")))."\n");
}
```

output

```
0: 00, 0012
1: 12, 123, 0012
2: 12, 123, 0012
3: 123
4: 
5: 
6:
```